# Parsing a JSON Array - how to?

Tags: android, json, parsing

I want to parse JSON from web site url, But I'm getting error when I'm using JSON array it's showing me in toast message "Json parsing error: Value [{"id":27553" how can I show my JSON app? anyone can help me to solve this issue? and sorry for my bad english.

Here is my java code

```
package info.jsonparsing;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "myweburl";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contactList = new ArrayList<>();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contacts");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString("id");
                        String name = c.getString("name");
                        String email = c.getString("email");
                        String address = c.getString("address");
                        String gender = c.getString("gender");

                        // Phone node is JSON Object
                        JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject("phone");
                        String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");
                        String home = phone.getString("home");
                        String office = phone.getString("office");

                        // tmp hash map for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put("id", id);
                        contact.put("name", name);
                        contact.put("email", email);
                        contact.put("mobile", mobile);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name", "email",
                    "mobile"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                    R.id.email, R.id.mobile});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

and there is also my json example

```
{[
    {
            "id": "111",
            "name": "test user",
            "email": "user@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "222",
            "name": "Johnny Depp",
            "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
```

]
}

Comment: That's not a valid JSON file, so you're going to get an error. There's nothing really you can do about this.

Comment: but when i check my json file in json validator its showing me that its valid

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that you try to get int as string :) Your id has `int` data type. Try smth like this:

```
int id = c.getInt("id");
```

and then you can show it as string. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like this

```
int id = c.getInt("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that, you are trying to parse an integer value by using getString("") method.

Change `String id = c.getString("id");` to `int id = c.getInt("id");`

Comment: the same error :(

Comment: Please debug each line and check which line is throwing that exception. That would give you a better idea, in addition post your complete json file.

Comment: i updated json file can you check?

Comment: Did you check which line throws that exception. Looking at your json I feel JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contacts"); this line has issue as there is no array with key "contacts". Can you try to change it to optArray

Comment: yes in json file i don't have contacts line but how can i change my code to read without that line?

Comment: I dont know if it is possible but you can try using JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.OptJsonArray("");

Comment: If nothing works try and add a key to your JsonArray in your api(backend).

Answer (score 0):

**The value of id key is not closed example it should be "id":"27553" your is**

**[{"id":27553"**

Thats why it is throwing exception 
The json should come in proper format 
or ask the value in integer from service